# Where can I find the up-to-date schedule for the Yangon Circular Train?

Tags: trains, online-resources, myanmar, timetables, yangon

Where can I find the up-to-date schedule for the [Yangon Circular Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangon_Circular_Railway)?

I've seen some old pictures and blog posts but I don't know:

- whether  the schedule still applies,
- whether the [end-of-2019 railway upgrade](https://www.globalnewlightofmyanmar.com/yangon-circular-railway-upgrade-to-be-complete-by-end-of-2019) temporarily alters the schedule,
- the schedule of the trains when departing from a station other than Yangon Central Station.

Picture of the 2014 Yangon Circular Train schedule [from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Yangon_Circular_Railway_Timetable_2014-12-01_small.jpg/285px-Yangon_Circular_Railway_Timetable_2014-12-01_small.jpg) (I believe from Yangon Central Station):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A blog from 2020](https://dailytravelpill.com/yangon-circular-train-railway/) seems to say that the timings are the same:

> Below is the Yangon circular train schedule for both directions (you can choose any of them). Please keep in mind that this timetable is not always accurate and the circular train can be late.
>
> 6.10 AM (RIGHT/LEFT) 
> 8.20 AM (RIGHT) 
> 8.35 AM (LEFT) 
> 9.30 AM (RIGHT) 
> 10.10 AM (RIGHT) 
> 10.45 AM (LEFT) 
> 11.30 AM (RIGHT) 
> 11.50 AM (RIGHT) 
> 12.25 PM (LEFT) 
> 1.05 PM (RIGHT) 
> 1.40 PM (LEFT) 
> 2.25PM (RIGHT) 
> 3.30PM (RIGHT) 
> 4.40PM (LEFT) 
> 5.10PM (RIGHT)

[Another](https://www.bordersofadventure.com/riding-the-yangon-circle-line-train/) provides a similar answer:

> The Yangon Circular Train departs daily from Yangon Central Railway Station from 8:30 am and departs every 45 minutes to an hour, from platforms 6 and 7.